Cannot detect a weblink in a email using SpamAssassin
In my fight against spam mails I want to check if a email contains a link to a website inside the body of an email.
If the mail does indeed contain a link, then I want to make a DNS lookup against SpamHaus ... or whatever similar DNS service to check if the link is pointing to a server that has an A record on the form 127.x.x.x.
See examples of ip addresses in use at SpamHaus here
My first attempt at detecting a link would be to create a regular expression that looks for if the body of a mail contains anything beginning with http:// or https:// and ends with a / or ?.
I ended up with the following regex by using RegEx101.com:
https?:\/\/((\w|\d)+\.)+\w+

If I got this right it should mean it matched any domain containing alphanumeric characters or alternatively is just an IP address.
The regex matches any string that has the following syntax.

It begins with http followed by an optional s.
Then it matches the following ://.

Then it matches:

It matches anything containing any characters [a-z] or the digits [0-9] followed by a period and this pattern has to be matched at least once. This is the domain name or subdomain name in the link.

Then followed by matching the characters [a-z] at least once. This is the TLD part of a domain name.


Finally:
It matches if the link ends with a / or ?.

I am well aware a link does not need to have a subpath.
This is an issue for another day. :-)
Similar: I will also leave out support for links to ipv4 and ipv6 addresses. :-)
I do not care for anything that comes after the / or ? because it has no influence for the following DNS lookup.
This lead me to add the following lines to local.cf:
body       BADLINKS     /https?:\/\/((\w|\d)+\.)+\w+/i
describe   BADLINKS     Email contains weblinks
score      BADLINKS     0.1

After I restarted SpamAssassin I tried testing if SpamAssassin was matching the rule by running the command: cat linktest | spamc -R.
The file linktest contains a confirmed spam mail with 3 links inside the body.
However I cannot see my test was triggered?
This was the output from running the command:
 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
 1.1 URIBL_GREY             Contains an URL listed in the URIBL greylist
                            [URIs: sendgrid.net]
 0.0 HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS From and EnvelopeFrom 2nd level
                            mail domains are different
 0.0 SPF_HELO_NONE          SPF: HELO does not publish an SPF Record
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
 0.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY         BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
-0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_EF          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
                            envelope-from domain
 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
                            valid
 0.0 T_KAM_HTML_FONT_INVALID Test for Invalidly Named or Formatted
                            Colors in HTML
 0.8 FROM_FMBLA_NEWDOM28    From domain was registered in last 14-28
                            days
-0.0 DKIMWL_WL_MED          DKIMwl.org - Medium trust sender

The mail that I am using contains amongst other this text:
 <img src=3D"https://u11846957.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/open?...">

The link inside the double quotes should be matched except the ending /wf/open?..., so what am I missing?

What's in linktest? A simple explanation is that the message doesn't actually contain a link in the body, perhaps if you did not know how exactly to separate the headers from the body. Please provide a [mre]. (And tangentially probably avoid the useless cat though that is completely unimportant here.)

\w already subsumes \d so your host expression can be simplified to (?:\w+\.)+\w+. Unlike in your prose description, it doesn't look for a trailing / or ?, so it will match https://www.30 out of https://www.30-something.example.com/

linktest is a received html formatted email. It is a bit long since it contains stylesheet and html formatted code, but is for the most part irrelevant, since I want to make a simple string search inside the code to locate anything that starts with http or https. I do not care if the link is written in bold/purple/whatever. I am only interested in which servers are linked to. Anyway: I did more google and solution was trivial. See below in a few minutes.

@tripleee: Oh I did't knew that. Regex101 said \w was a word character - so I took it litteral as being a replacement for [a-z] only.

To permit dashes too, a character class is more efficient than round parentheses; https?:\/\/(?:[-\w]+\.)+\w+(?=[?\/:])

Thank you. It has been too long since I did regex on a regular basis and even longer since took a deep dive in perl. So it is going to be a small challenge to do the actual DNS lookup in my subtests. :-)

Doh!
Word of advice: Know the difference between how body works vs rawbody in SpamAssassin rules.
The rule was not matched when I used body in the local.cf.
What I needed to use was rawbody like so:
rawbody    BAD_LINKS     /https?:\/\/((\w|\d)+\.)+\w+/i
describe   BAD_LINKS     Email contains weblinks
score      BAD_LINKS     0.1

After restarting SpamAssassin I got the following result:
 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
-0.0 RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2      RBL: Average reputation (+2)
                            [149.72.232.26 listed in wl.mailspike.net]
 0.0 SPF_HELO_NONE          SPF: HELO does not publish an SPF Record
 0.0 HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS From and EnvelopeFrom 2nd level
                            mail domains are different
 0.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY         BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message

 0.1 BAD_LINKS              RAW: Email contains weblinks <<<--- My rule

-0.1 DKIM_VALID_EF          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
                            envelope-from domain
 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
                            valid
-0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
 1.1 URIBL_GREY             Contains an URL listed in the URIBL greylist
                            [URIs: sendgrid.net]
 0.0 T_KAM_HTML_FONT_INVALID Test for Invalidly Named or Formatted
                            Colors in HTML
 0.8 FROM_FMBLA_NEWDOM28    From domain was registered in last 14-28
                            days
-0.0 DKIMWL_WL_MED          DKIMwl.org - Medium trust sender

